# Protobuf memory error when adding 6 array messages

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I am getting this error: `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67112960 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\...` when i adding 6 array message in my proto file. I am using php protobuf protocol buffers for serialization.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message data {
    .data_step_one test = 2;
}

message data_step_one {
    .data_step_two test1 = 1;
}

message data_step_two {
    .data_step_three test2 = 2;
}

message data_step_three {
    .data_step_four test3 = 2;
}

message data_step_four {
    .data_step_five test4 = 14;
}

message data_step_five {
    .data_step_six test5 = 1;
}

message data_step_six {
    string something = 1;
}
```

When i remove string (`string something = 1;`) from last six array

> message data_step_six {
> }

its worked without that error. Just i got that error when i add something in six message. I am new in this protobuf message, so don't understand where was the problem and how will i solve it.

**Updated More:**

This is my original data for post method (I followed this for create proto messages):

```
1 {
  1: 1
  2: 58480067980758310
  4: 0
}
2 {
  1 {
    1: 112
    2 {
      1: id:a-7769307577821621420
      2 {
        14 {
          1 {
            1: mid:b-6430467773153509964
            2 {
              1: 1
              2: mcacc.com
              3: Emma Ava
              10: mcacc.com
            }
            3 {
              1: 1
              2: scssd.com
            }
            7: 1627577996674
            8: Test
            9 {
              2 {
                1: 0
                2: <div dir='auto'>This is test.</div>
              }
              7: 1
            }
            11: ^a
            11: ^all
            11: ^f_bt
            11: ^f_cl
            11: ^f_btns
            11: ^pfg
            18: 1627577996674
            36 {
              6: 0
            }
            37 {
              4: 0
            }
            42: 0
            52: s:23cbdb9f4cd2713a|#mid:b-6430467773153509964|0
          }
          3: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
3 {
  1: 4
  2: 518600
  5 {
    1: 30
    2: 0
  }
  7: 1
  8 {
    1: ^wa_ready
    1: ^f
    1: ^t_z
    2: ^r
  }
}
4 {
  2: 1
  3: 1627577996728
  4: 1
  5: 57
}
5: 2
```

This is proto message i created:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message rs_request {
    .unknown_int_data unknown_int = 1;
    .unknown_int_data1 unknown_int1 = 2;
    .unknown_int_data2 unknown_int2 = 3;
    .unknown_int_data3 unknown_int3 = 4;
    bool unknown_int4 = 5;
}

message unknown_int_data {
    bool unint = 1;
    fixed32 unknown = 2;
    bool unknown1 = 4;
}

message unknown_int_data1 {
    .unknown_int_datas unknown2 = 1;
}

message unknown_int_datas {
    int32 unknown3 = 1;
    .unknown_int_datas1 unknown4 = 2;
}

message unknown_int_datas1 {
    string threadaId = 1;
    .unknown_int_datass unknowns = 2;
}

message unknown_int_datass {
    .unknown_int_datas2 unknown5 = 14;
}

message unknown_int_datas2 {
    .unknown_int_datas3 unknown6 = 1;
    bool unknown7 = 3;
}

message unknown_int_datas3 {
    string msgaId = 1;
    .unknown_int_datas4 unknown9 = 2;
    .unknown_int_datas5 unknown10 = 3;
    fixed32 unknown11 = 7;
    string subject = 8;
    .unknown_int_datas6 unknown12 = 9;
    string unknown13 = 11;
    fixed32 unknown14 = 18;
    .unknown_int_datas7 unknown15 = 36;
    .unknown_int_datas8 unknown16 = 37;
    int32 unknown17 = 42;
    string unknown18 = 52;
}

message unknown_int_datas4 {
    bool unknown19 = 1;
    string from_domain = 2;
    string from_name = 3;
    string from_domain_again = 10;
}

message unknown_int_datas5 {
    bool unknown20 = 1;
    string to_domain = 2;
}

message unknown_int_datas6 {
    .unknown_int_datas9 unknown21 = 2;
    bool unknown22 = 7;
}

message unknown_int_datas9 {
    bool unknown23 = 1;
    string msg = 2;
}

message unknown_int_datas7 {
    bool unknown24 = 6;
}

message unknown_int_datas8 {
    bool unknown25 = 4;
}

message unknown_int_data2 {
    bool unknowsthree = 1;
    uint32 unknowsthree1 = 2;
    .unknowsthree_data unknowsthree2 = 5;
    bool unknowsthree3 = 7;
    .unknowsthree_datas unknowsthree4 = 8;
}

message unknowsthree_data {
    int32 unknowsthree5 = 1;
    bool unknowsthree6 = 2;
}

message unknowsthree_datas {
    string unknowsthree7 = 1;
    string unknowsthree8 = 2;
}

message unknown_int_data3 {
    bool unknown26 = 2;
    fixed32 unknown27 = 3;
    bool unknown28 = 4;
    int32 unknown29 = 5;
}
```

and this is request model json for post (mcRequestModel.php):

```
      "unknown_int1" => [
            "unknown2" => [
                "unknown4" => [
                    "unknowns" => [
                        "unknown5" => [
                            "unknown6" => [
                                "unknown9" => [
                                    "from_domain" => "mcacc.com",
                                    "from_name" => "Emma Ava",
                                    "from_domain_again" => "mcacc.com"
                                ],
                                "unknown10" => [
                                    "to_domain" => "scssd.com"
                                ],
                                "subject" => "Test",
                                "unknown12" => [
                                    "unknown21" => [
                                        "msg" => "<div dir='auto'>This is test.</div>"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Trying to get buffer compiler using php-protobuf:

```
$mcRequest = new mcRequestModel();
$class = new \rs_request();
$class->parseFromJsonStream($mcRequest);
var_dump($class);
```

When i remove all data from array `unknown_int_datas3` i got buffer compiler arrays larger output but not getting compiler output when not remove data from `unknown_int_datas3`and just getting `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67112960 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\...`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the compiler is challenged by the levels of nesting in your messages.

I don't use PHP but I pasted your proto into Marc Gravell's [protogen](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/#) tool, selected PHP and it was able to compile.

The nesting in your messages is unusual and I was unable to understand why you would want to do this. Some context in your question to explain what you're trying to achieve may be useful.

With your current structure, in JSON, a `data` message would be:

```
{
  test: {
    test1: {
      test2: {
        test3: {
          test4: {
            test5: {
              something: "...."
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Google's [style guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#message_and_field_names) recommends `PascalCase` messages names (i.e. `DataStepTwo`) and `snake_case` field names (which you are doing `test`)

Your messages should probably use `1` consistently for the field numbers. Each of your messages only have 1 field so, unless you're intentionally avoiding collisions you may wish to avoid using `2` and `14`.

Comment: I can't avoid `2` and `14` its needed bcz json data have it. Plz check my post, i updated it. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the updates. What you refer to as "original data" has an unusual structure. The structure is entirely unfamiliar to me. Are you using some 3rd-party service to post this data to? Or something you've written? From what I can tell, it may be better for you to reformat that data into a more conventional format and then generate protobufs based on that.